# Last Opened Documents using Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way to get the last opened files of an application? I know with LSSharedFileListCreate you can get an array of the global recent documents of the user but I was wondering if it was possible to get the recent documents for a specific application, such as Xcode, using cocoa or objective-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a public API for getting recent documents of apps other than your own. The recent files are saved as plists in `~/Library/Preferences` though, so you could just read those directly.

Note however that the format of these plists might change with future OS upgrades, so you should ideally not rely on this.

Here's an example for reading the recent documents of Xcode:

```
NSString *bundleID = @"com.apple.dt.Xcode";
NSString *prefPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Preferences"];
NSString *recentFilesFileName = [bundleID stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"LSSharedFileList.plist"];
NSString *recentFilesPath = [prefPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:recentFilesFileName];

NSArray *recentDocumentItems = [[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:recentFilesPath] objectForKey:@"RecentDocuments"] objectForKey:@"CustomListItems"];
for (NSDictionary *recentDocumentItem in recentDocumentItems) {
    NSString *name = [recentDocumentItem objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSData *bookmarkData = [recentDocumentItem objectForKey:@"Bookmark"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *bookmarkURL = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmarkData options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutMounting | NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI relativeToURL:nil bookmarkDataIsStale:NULL error:&error];
    if (bookmarkURL) {
        NSLog(@"File name: %@", name);
        NSLog(@"URL: %@", bookmarkURL);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Could not resolve URL for file %@: %@", name, error);
    }
}
```

This won't work in a sandboxed app of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-[NSDocumentController recentDocumentURLs]`, which retrieves an array of URLs of the most recently opened documents:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] recentDocumentURLs];
```

Comment: I know `-[NSDocumentController recentDocumentURLs]` will return recent documents for the application that is being run, but is there a way to specify which application we want to get the recent documents from, like to get Xcode's recent documents?

Comment: No. Your only option is in LSSharedFileList, and even then, it's only for all the user's most recent files. Sorry for the misunderstanding; it's only from your comment that I figured out what you really wanted.

Comment: There may be a way to do it, something along the lines of opening an application's preference file. Then again, if you were to try that, there may be sandboxing issues with which to contend.